# Problema con los enums

Tags: c#, enum

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Ejercicio_2
{
  class Program
  {
    enum direcion { arriba=1,abajo=3,derecha=2,izquieda=4};
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string num = "";
        Console.WriteLine("Escribe la direcion que desees tomar");
        num = Console.ReadLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < num.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", num.Substring(i, 1));
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Hola mi problema es el siguiente, el enunciado del ejercicio dice que tenemos un dron que puede ir arriba abajo derecha izquierda. Que asociemos un valor entero a cada enum. Que introduzcamos por teclado números (1,2,3,4) y que nos muestre arriba derecha izquieda abajo. El problema es que yo pongo arriba en la inicialización delos enums un numero por ejemplo arriba=1 y luego si yo entro por teclado 1 no me sale arriba me muestra 1. No se como puedo hacerlo. Había pensado en guardar lo que pongas en una cadena como en el ejemplo y luego comprar carácter a carácter y si es un 1 que muestre arriba, si es 2 que muestre derecha, etc. Pero no se como comparar los caracteres de las cadenas. Pero la cuestión seria utilizando los enums, porque el ejercicio trata de practicar con ellos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer es buscar el valor dentro del `enum` por su index:

```
class Program
  {
    enum direccion { arriba=1, abajo=3, derecha=2, izquieda=4 };
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string num = "";
        Console.WriteLine("Escribe la dirección que desees tomar");
        num = Console.ReadLine();
        direccion d = (direccion)Int32.Parse(num);

        Console.WriteLine(d);
    }
  }
```

**Edit:**

Primero recibimos el `string` que introduce el usuario, aquí en vez de hacer el `substring` puedes hacer un `split` por comas, creo que sera mas fácil:

```
var numeros = str.Split(',');
```

De esta forma transformas tu `string` introducido en un `array`.
Ahora solo tienes que hacer un bucle recorriendo este `array`:

```
foreach (var numero in numeros)
{
        direccion d = (direccion)Int32.Parse(numero);

        Console.WriteLine(d);
}
```

Aquí tienes que entender un poco como funcionan los `enums`.

**Simplificando:** es un array de *llave = valor*, es decir, cuando has creado el `enum` le has puesto valores *"arriba", "abajo", "etc"* y les has asignado un indice *1, 3, etc*.

**Para sacar un valor de esta array hay varias formas:**

1. **Por valor:**

   ```
   Console.WriteLine(direccion.arriba)  // Esto nos devolverá "arriba"
   ```
2. **Por indice:**

   ```
   Console.WriteLine((direccion)1)  // Esto nos devolverá "arriba"
   ```

**Tambien podemos buscar que indice tiene un valor:**

```
Console.WriteLine((int)direccion.arriba); // Esto nos devolverá 1
```

Comment: ¿Nadie va a comentar que hay una errata en *direcion*?

Comment: Esto no resuelve mi duda porque yo necesito que introduzca 1,2,3,4 sea como sea el orden y luego me muestre en este caso arriba derecha abajo izquieda. Y con lo que tu me dices no me ha funcionado, me sigue mostrando por pantalla 1,2,3,4 .

Comment: @winnie si, esta respuesta funciona. Lo que debes hacer es parsear `num.Substring(i, 1)` en tu bucle a int, y hacer un cast a dirección:  `Console.WriteLine("{0}", (direcion)int.Parse(num.Substring(i, 1)));`

Comment: Es cierto, me disculpo. Podríais explicarme porque debo hacer eso para entenderlo. Seré un cazurro pero no lo entiendo, si podéis hacerme una breve explicación porfavor. No entiendo por ejemplo el " direcion d = (direcion)Int32.Parse(num);"

Comment: Dmyto, deberías efectivamente explicar por qué y cómo funciona el código de tu respuesta. Veo que es tu primera respuesta,asi que te recomiendo leer [answer]

Comment: Estoy editando la respuesta, un momento

Comment: Editado, e intententado explicar un poco como podrias resolver el ejercicio. Perdonad si no se entiende bien.

Comment: Mucho mejor,gracias.